# How can I clear the previous position of the circle in my canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, pong

I'm trying to make Pong using canvas with JavaScript.

It has been many years since I made any game, and therefore am quite the beginner.

I have a problem where I am trying to move the ball (just its x position, for now) and trying to remove its previous position. The code I am using worked for the paddle (up and down keys to move it).

But, it doesn't seem to want to work with the ball.

What am I doing wrong?

```
this.draw = function() {
    ctx.clearRect(this.prevX - this.radius, this.prevY - this.radius, this.radius * 2, this.radius * 2);

    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    this.prevX = this.x;
    this.prevY = this.y;
 }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/UvGVb/).

I know I am using `clearRect()`, but I was under the impression it just removes a rectangular portion of the canvas.

> `clearRect(x,y,width,height)` : Clears the specified area and makes it fully transparent

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes).

Feel free to give me any other tips too, as I'm pretty much a beginner with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually because you are not calling `beginPath`, so every new circle you draw also redraws all of the old circles!

Fix here with illustration:

http://jsfiddle.net/UvGVb/15/

Take out the call to `beginPath` to see what was happening before.

Comment: I knew I was missing something! Thanks very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on canvas, so I will go with the "other tips too" plead. :-) If you step away from canvas and instead use html elements like div to draw your paddles and ball, you won't have to bother with removing, only moving. Then there are lots of libraries to help you with element positioning, animation etc, of which jQuery would be my first choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I deliberately chose to canvas so I could get familiar with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be giving incorrect coordinates to the 'clearrect' function when you render the new position of the ball. Some of your references to 'this' look like they might be dodgy too:

```
var that = this;
```

The above is inside a function - I think it is referencing 'this' in the local scope of the function rather than the scope of the ball (which is I assume what you intend). You can set up a reference to this (ball scope) and use that from inside inner functions if you need to.

Try printing out the coordinates of the ball, and the coordinates of its previous position. You can then work out whether or not you are clearing the right area of the canvas. I'd also check your use of the this keyword and make sure it's in the right scope for what you want to do.

I have only had a quick look so I'm sorry if I've misunderstood what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I [tried](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Y6gWZ/) changing `clearRect()` to `fillRect()` and it positioned the boxes correctly. So I don't think it is that.

Comment: Is there anything else that happens after clearRect() that might be overwriting that area of the canvas after it has already been cleared?

Comment: I don't think so, but then again, I'm a canvas novice so I'm not 100% sure.